# JavaScript unresponsive error on recursive calling of function in for loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

HI I'm iterating control from webpage, i'm getting script unresponsive error if controls are more than 500, though as per my requirement control can grow. I'm using following code.

```
function callme(val1,val2){
 (var i=0;i<1750;i++)
    {
    var val=some custom function();
    var val3=some custom function();
    callme(val,val3)
    }
   }
```

How to prevent this situation, so that all recursive call should run in asynchronous order.
Kindly suggest.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Don't know what's going on, but what's with the whitespace? Or lack of it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, having 500 controls in a page is not really a good idea. You might want to look at pagination/splitting based on what your page and code is supposed to be doing.

Async is an option if call me does not return a value and you are not worried about updating the UI immediately. You could set the recursive call to run async by using setTimeout.